# If every element of $H$ and $G/H$ is a square, then prove that so is every element of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of an abelian group $G$ such that every element of $H$ can be written as $b^2,\, b \in G$ and similarly for $G/H$. Then how to prove that every element of $G$ can also be written as a square ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $g\in G$, There exists $a\in G$ such that $(aH)^2=gH$, which means that there exists $h\in H$ such that $g=a^2h$. Also, since there exists $h'\in H$ such that $(h')^2=h$, thus
$$g=(ah')^2,$$
and the proof is completed.

Answer (score 7):

*Alternative proof.* Apply the Snake Lemma to
$$\begin{array}{c} 0 & \rightarrow & H & \rightarrow & G & \rightarrow & G/H & \rightarrow & 0  \\ & & 2 \downarrow ~~& & 2 \downarrow ~~ & & 2 \downarrow ~~ \\0 & \rightarrow & H & \rightarrow & G & \rightarrow & G/H & \rightarrow & 0 \end{array}$$

Comment: No Snake Lemma, just diagram chasing.

Comment: 1. Of course there are elementary and direct proofs (see the other answers). 2. Why not using the Snake Lemma? (You write "No Snake Lemma", is this a command?) 3. The Snake Lemma is usually proven via a diagram chase. So there is no need to repeat it, once you know the Lemma. 4. The diagram chase here coincides with the proof in the other answers. But the whole point of my answer is that, as soon as you know this general and useful result - the Snake Lemma - you don't have to think or calculate or chase elements at all.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Given any $a\in G$, you can write $aH = x^2H$ for some $x\in G$. Now proceed.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** Note that $gH=aHaH=a^2H$ so elements of the coset $gH$ have the form...what?

Comment: your answer seems to be a duplicate of Ted Shefrin's answer. sorry I should downvote it.

Comment: @user138171 If you check the time-stamps, they were posted simultaneously!

Comment: The last edit is after that. I checked the edits.

Comment: @user138171 Sure, but the edits just removed a lot of bumph and replaced it with the word "coset". The answer is, fundamentally, the same.

Comment: Instead of editing to an existing answer you could delete the answer.

Comment: @user Why, because I made it more readable?

Comment: This is what you think.